# C# Unit Test dependency Injection

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am a student and for a project I have to write tests made with C#. Here I have to use the services that I wrote. How do I add decency injection in a C# Unit test?
Also I have to use AutoMapper, does this work the same way?

This is what I've tried:

```
public class DiveTests
{
    private readonly IDiveService _diveService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public DiveTests(IDiveService diveService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _diveService = diveService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void AddAsync_InputGoodDive_CreateNewDive()
    {
        Guid id = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2020-12-23T17:04:43.802Z");
        Dive dive = new Dive()
        {
            Id = id,
            Depth = 15,
            DiveDate = dateTime,
            DivePlace = "hello"
        };
        DiveRequestDto diveRequestDto = _mapper.Map<DiveRequestDto>(dive);
        await _diveService.AddAsync(diveRequestDto);
        var result = await _diveService.GetByIdAsync(id);
        Assert.Equal(result.Id, id);
    }
}
```

And this is an other constructor I've tried:

```
    public DiveTests()
    {
        if (_mapper == null)
        {
            var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfiles());
            });
            IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
            _mapper = mapper;
            _diveService = diveService;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dependency Injection is achieved by an application host configuring and initializing the required assets that resolve dependencies. In the scenario of a unit test a unit test runner is your host and its purpose is to run unit tests. You should instantiate a concrete implementation of `IDiveService` and use a mocking framework (such as [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)) to mock any dependencies that the concrete type has.

Answer (score 0):

if  you are adding unit tests for IDiveService/DiveService ; then no need to call /use IMapper witth in your unit test:AddAsync_InputGoodDive_CreateNewDive()

public class DiveTests
{
private readonly IDiveService _diveService;

```
public DiveTests()
{
    _diveService = new DIveSevice(); // or can create this instance at unit test level
}

[Fact]
public async void AddAsync_InputGoodDive_CreateNewDive()
{
    // ARRANGE
    Guid id = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2020-12-23T17:04:43.802Z");
    DiveRequestDto diveRequestDto = new DiveRequestDto
    {
        Depth = 15,
        DiveDate = dateTime,
        DivePlace = "hello"
    };

    // ACT
    await _diveService.AddAsync(diveRequestDto);
    var result = await _diveService.GetByIdAsync(id);

    // ASSERT
    Assert.Equal(result.Id, id);
}
```

}